# CORDOVA NOT ACCEPTING file://

Tags: android, cordova, three.js, cors, web-deployment

I am making a app for android in cordova using three.js. But the issue is I am unable to load images from javascript by file:// protocol.
I keep getting the following error in chrome console

> Access to Image at 'file://image.png/' from origin 'null' has been
>   blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

The error is caused by this code snippet :

```
var Texture1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/image.png'),
 Texture2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/image2.png');
```

The same code doesn't run in browser locally (file protocol), but it runs when I connect it to localhost:8000 (http protocol). I know this is a CORS issue but the cordova white list plugin states that the file:// should be accessible, but they are not.

and here's my snippet from config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="file://*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
```

Comment: it might be a CSP issue: https://content-security-policy.com/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding a liberal Content Security Policy in your index.html, something like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content: *; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

Comment: not working... tried more meta from [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) but stull not working